# Default content for new record with Nova Simple Repeatable

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm using the [Nova Simple Repeatable](https://github.com/outl1ne/nova-simple-repeatable/), which works perfectly well as described to enter and edit a set of rows saved to a JSON field in the database.

I have an additional need, which is to pre-populate a set of these rows when a new record is created.

Before upgrading to Nova 4, I could do this using the Rows field of 64robots/nova-fields and could use the ->withMeta() method to add data that I generated, but this package doesn't work with Nova 4.

Does anyone know how I might do this? Posted as an issue in the repo for this module too...

Thanks!